# Complete sparse data in Graphite

Tags: python, graphite

I have a list of objects that each contain: Product, Price, Time. It basically holds product price change over time. So, for each price change you'll get a record with the product name, the new price and the exact second of the change.

I'm sending the data to graphite using the timestamp (written in python):

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('my-host-ip', 2003))
message = 'my.metric.prefix.%s %s %d\n' % (product, price, timestamp)
sock.sendall(message)
sock.close()
```

Thing is, as prices do not change very often, the data points are very sparsed which mean I get a point per product in a frequency of hours/days. If I look at Graphite at the exact time of the price change, I can see the data point. But if I want to look at price change over time, I would like to draw a constant line from the data point of the price change going forward.

I tried using:

```
keepLastValue(my.metric.prefix.*)
```

I would work only if I look at the data points in a time frame of a few minutes, but not hours (surely not days). Is there a way to do something like that in Graphite? Or I have to put some redundant data every minute to describe the missing points?

Answer (score 1):

I believe using `keepLastValue` doesn't work for you for a coarser time interval due to aggregation rules defined in [`storage-aggregation.conf`](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config-carbon.html#storage-aggregation-conf). You can try using `xFilesFactor = 0` and `aggregationMethod = last` to get always the last value of the metric at each aggregated point.

However I think your concrete use case is much better resolved by using [StatsD gauges](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/docs/metric_types.md#gauges). Basically you can set an arbitrary numerical value for a gauge in StatsD and it will send (flush) its value to Graphite every 10 seconds by default. You can set the flush interval to a shorter period, like 1 second, if you really need to record the second of the change. If the gauge is not updated at the next flush, StatsD will send the previous value.

So basically StatsD gauges do what you say about sending redundant data to describe missing points.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm gonna check it out. About StatsD, as far as I understand, i can't send historic data with statsd, am I wrong? I need to fill in historic data and not data from now going forward

Comment: I think you're right you can't send historical data with StatsD.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as well with sparse data.
I used the whisper database tools outlined in the link below to update my whisper files which were aggregating load data on 10 minute intervals.

https://github.com/graphite-project/whisper

First examine my file using whisper-info:

```
/opt/graphite/bin/whisper-info.py /opt/graphite/storage/whisper/test/system/myserver/n001/loadave.wsp
```

Then fix aggregation methods using whisper-resize:

```
/opt/graphite/bin/whisper-resize.py --xFilesFactor=0 --aggregationMethod=last /opt/graphite/storage/whisper/test/system/myserver/n001/loadave.wsp 600:259200
```

Please be cautious using whisper-resize as it can result in data loss if you aren't careful!